# KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

при попытке открытия xlsx файла появляется такая ошибка

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/4r4r5/PycharmProjects/untitled2/Main.py", line 10, in
>   
>       matcher.rename_drugs()   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\Matcher.py", line 196, in
>   rename_drugs
>       self.__directory + file)  # for files from directory creates csv copy   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\Matcher.py",
>   line 94, in __csv_from_excel
>       wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(datapath)   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 314, in load_workbook
>       reader.read()   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 274, in read
>       self.read_strings()   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\PycharmProjects\untitled2\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py",
>   line 143, in read_strings
>       with self.archive.open(strings_path,) as src:   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1470, in open
>       zinfo = self.getinfo(name)   File "C:\Users\4r4r5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py",
>   line 1398, in getinfo
>       'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name) KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"

мой код

```
def __csv_from_excel(filename, datapath):  # read from datapath; write to filename  
    try:  
        if (datapath[-4:]) == "xlsx":
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(datapath)
            filenames = []
            sheets = wb.sheetnames
        for sheet in sheets:
            sh = wb[str(sheet)]
            with open(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv", 'tw', newline='') as f:
                filenames.append(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv")
                wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=";")
                for row in sh.rows:
                    temp = []
                    for cell in row:
                        temp.append(cell.value)
                    wr.writerow(temp)
                f.close()
        return filenames
    elif (datapath[-4:]) == ".xls":
        wb = xlrd.open_workbook(datapath, encoding_override="cp1251")
        sheetlist = wb.sheet_names()
        filenames = []
        for sheet in sheetlist:
            sh = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet)
            with open(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv", 'tw', newline='') as f:
                filenames.append(filename[:-4] + sheet + ".csv")
                wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, delimiter=";")
                for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
                    wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
                f.close()
        return filenames
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print(datapath)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина

Comment: Небось эти файлы сформированы в 1С?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я точно не скажу, так как сам их не формирую, но скорее всего именно так

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема с excel-файлами, которые были сгенерированы в 1С. Чтобы твой код принял файл, тебе нужно что-нибудь поменять в нём (ширина ячеек, цвет ячеек, что-нибудь да изменить). Тогда запашет.

Answer (score 4):

Это довольно старая ошибка - `KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/sharedStrings.xml' in the archive"`.

Если открыть **xlsx** файл как zip-архив, то можно увидеть что нужный файл есть, но первая буква - большая: 'xl/SharedStrings.xml'.

Похоже генерит такое какая-то из старых версий 1С или что-то похожее.

Решений может быть несколько:

1. Использовать библиотеку **xlrd** v 1.2 - в ней был код, который учитывал подобные ошибки в архиве. В текущей версии - 2.x поддержку **xlsx** из этой библиотеке выкинули.
2. Исправить архив с помощью **libreoffice** - он умеет корректно открывать такие файлы.
3. Исправить архив самостоятельно - перепаковав с исправленным именем.

Answer (score 3):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, надеюсь, мой ответ кому-нибудь поможет.

```py
import shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile

# Создаем временную папку
tmp_folder = '/tmp/convert_wrong_excel/'
os.makedirs(tmp_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Распаковываем excel как zip в нашу временную папку
with ZipFile('yourfile.xlsx') as excel_container:
    excel_container.extractall(tmp_folder)

# Переименовываем файл с неверным названием
wrong_file_path = os.path.join(tmp_folder, 'xl', 'SharedStrings.xml')
correct_file_path = os.path.join(tmp_folder, 'xl', 'sharedStrings.xml')
os.rename(wrong_file_path, correct_file_path) 

# Запаковываем excel обратно в zip и переименовываем в исходный файл
shutil.make_archive('yourfile', 'zip', tmp_folder)
os.rename('yourfile.zip', 'yourfile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2):

У меня так же выгрузка файлов из 1С.
Смог обойти решениез без архивов вот таким способом:
Открываю через xlrd:

```
files_SPB_new = xlrd.open_workbook(r'X:\Отчет.xlsx')
```

А потом уже через панду, т.к. у меня все настроено на работу через Pandas

```
files_SPB_new = pd.read_excel(files_SPB_new)
```

---

xlrd версия 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Просто попробуйте использовать pandas:

```
    # вернет словарь датафреймов с ключами в качестве названий листов excel файла
dict_of_dfs = pd.read_excel('<path to excel file>', sheet_name=None)    # sheet_name=None returns all sheets
```

И затем, чтобы использовать датафрейм:

```
df_sheet1 = dict_of_dfs['Sheet 1']
```

Также если вы собираетесь использовать библиотеки для работы с excel файлами, pandas может послужить конвертером и полученный датафрейм можно сохранить как excel файл:

```
df_sheet1.to_excel(excel_writer='<path to save excel file>', sheet_name='Sheet 1')
excel_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='<path to save excel file>')
```